# Correct format for Cucumber scenarios

Tags: format, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I read in a Cucumber book that the format for a Cucumber feature scenario should be that of a Gherkin scenario, i.e.:
Given-When-Then

To simplify things, let's omit the And elements that can appear in a scenario.

I have often seen in my current project several scenarios defined like this:
Scenario X
Given-Then-When-Then

Is this format correct? Cucumber accepts it, but is it good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Given`, `When`, and `Then` keywords are actually aliases of the same method, so they can be used interchangeably.  `Gherkin`is just providing more human-readable hooks to write scenarios.

As far as a `Given/Then/When/Then` sequence in a scenario, that'll work, but it does seem a bit unusual.  I realize that you're trying to keep your question simple, but this sounds like a possible case for using `And` or `But`.  For example: `Given/And/When/Then` or `Given/But/When/Then`.  And FWIW, you can use `*` to start a step if you want to avoid the semantic gymnastics of `Given/When/Then/And/But`

Answer (score 2):

I mostly agree with @orde but I feel the necessity to use the terms for specific purposes. Given, for me, is always a step that sets up the test. It is the situation that one starts with. I recommend using step definitions that do not exercise the software under test.

```
Given I am a registered user
And I am logged in
And I have a product in my shopping cart
```

When is for triggering the test. It can be more than one step, but that's confusing.

```
When I delete the item from my cart
```

Then is for verifying the expected result. I use it to check what is as a result of the when.

```
Then there are not items in my shopping cart
```

I see the different terms as ways to help the reader know which step serves which purpose without having to read the code in the step definitions.